# (Tensorflow) What is the correct NN needed for this task?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm about to start developing a neural net here with Tensorflow, but before I get into it too deep, I was hoping I could get some feedback on exactly what type of neural net I will need for this (If a net is the right way to go about this at all)

I need the NN to input an image, and output another image. This will be used for path-mapping on a robot I'm working on. The input image will be a [disparity map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607312/difference-between-disparity-map-and-disparity-image-in-stereo-matching), and the output will be a "driveable map" (an image that displays what in the scene can be driven on, and what can't)

I have built a dataset using Unity 3d. Here is an example from the set:

disparity map

[image: Disparity Map]

driveable map:

[image: Driveable map]

As you can probably see, white represents the area where my robot can drive and black is where it can't. I will need the NN to take a disparity map, and give me back a "driveable map". Can this be done?
     Thanks!

Comment: If anyone needs me to clarify, PLEASE let me know.

Comment: Also, If this question needs to be closed, just tell me why and I'll close it my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm not an expert. Since there hasn't been a response on this and if you are still looking, the vocabulary I would use to describe this type of problem is [disparity networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04309.pdf) and segmentation. Your best bet may be a specific type of disparity network: [U-net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! After looking into it a bit more, the type of network that I needed for this was a "Segmentation Net" as you mentioned. This inputs an image, and outputs an image. (Exactly what I was looking for)